# 100% wide child element is not filling its container

Tags: html, css

I'm making tables with scrollable body in HTML. I have the `<thead>` set to `display:table; width:100%`, but at varying times it ends up being 1 or 2 pixels short of the full width of the `<table>`.

[image: table with yellow background and grey header, with yellow seen to right of header]

(a) Why is this happening?
(b) How do I work around it?

Run the code snippet full screen and resize your browser window to see yellow appear to the right of the header occasionally.

```css
body { background:#666; display:flex }
table {
    display:flex; flex-flow:column; 
    margin-right:10px; height:120px;
    background:#ff3;
}
thead {
  flex:0 0 auto;
  width:100%;
  background:#999;
}
thead, tbody tr { display:table; table-layout:fixed }
th { text-align:left }
tbody { flex:1 1 auto; display:block; overflow-y:auto }
tbody tr { width:100% }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead><tr><th>title</th><th>artist</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>No Ordinary Morning</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>From Where I Stand</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Come Back</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Offshore</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Don't Give Up (feat. Bryan Adams)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Spirit (Chicane Rework Mix) [feat. Jewel]</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Halcyon</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sunstroke</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Stoned In Love (feat. Tom Jones)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Wake Up (feat. Keane)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Come Tomorrow</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Leaving Town (feat. Salt Tank)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead><tr><th>title</th><th>artist</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>No Ordinary Morning</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>From Where I Stand</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Come Back</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Offshore</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Don't Give Up (feat. Bryan Adams)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Spirit (Chicane Rework Mix) [feat. Jewel]</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Halcyon</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sunstroke</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Stoned In Love (feat. Tom Jones)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Wake Up (feat. Keane)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Come Tomorrow</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Leaving Town (feat. Salt Tank)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead><tr><th>title</th><th>artist</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>No Ordinary Morning</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>From Where I Stand</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Come Back</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Offshore</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Don't Give Up (feat. Bryan Adams)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Spirit (Chicane Rework Mix) [feat. Jewel]</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Halcyon</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sunstroke</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Stoned In Love (feat. Tom Jones)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Wake Up (feat. Keane)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Come Tomorrow</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Leaving Town (feat. Salt Tank)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead><tr><th>title</th><th>artist</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>No Ordinary Morning</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>From Where I Stand</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Come Back</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Offshore</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Don't Give Up (feat. Bryan Adams)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Spirit (Chicane Rework Mix) [feat. Jewel]</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Halcyon</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sunstroke</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Stoned In Love (feat. Tom Jones)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Wake Up (feat. Keane)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Come Tomorrow</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Leaving Town (feat. Salt Tank)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's going 100% full width for me in Chrome on Mac OS X. Sounds like a browser specific bug. What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: I can reproduce on Linux Chrome v46.0.2490.86

Comment: @www139 Chrome 46.0.2490.86 and Safari 9.0.1 on Mac OS X. Did you run the snippet, make it "Full page", and then try resizing the browser window width?

Comment: Had to full screen the snippet to see it.

Comment: Further investigation in Chrome shows that the width of the table is sometimes "138.25" or "138.75" pixels wide, while the thead inside it is only "138".

Comment: More interesting: changing from `display:table` to `display:block` fixes the issue. Why is a 100% wide block different from a 100% table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the resize of the browser. On Chrome the space appears.

You have the possibility to increase the width of `thead` to `101%`. Add `overflow:hidden;` to `table` and the space should be disappear.

Here the example:

```css
body { background:#666; display:flex }
table {
    display:flex; 
    flex-flow:column; 
    margin-right:10px; height:120px;
    background:#ff3;
    overflow:hidden /** add this to hide the overflow of the thead. */;
}
thead {
  flex:0 0 auto;
  width:101% /** change from 100% to 101% */;
  background:#999;

}
thead, tbody tr { display:table; table-layout:fixed }
th { text-align:left }
tbody { flex:1 1 auto; display:block; overflow-y:auto }
tbody tr { width:100% }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead><tr><th>title</th><th>artist</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>No Ordinary Morning</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>From Where I Stand</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Come Back</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Offshore</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Don't Give Up (feat. Bryan Adams)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Spirit (Chicane Rework Mix) [feat. Jewel]</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Halcyon</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sunstroke</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Stoned In Love (feat. Tom Jones)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Wake Up (feat. Keane)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Come Tomorrow</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Leaving Town (feat. Salt Tank)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead><tr><th>title</th><th>artist</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>No Ordinary Morning</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>From Where I Stand</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Come Back</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Offshore</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Don't Give Up (feat. Bryan Adams)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Spirit (Chicane Rework Mix) [feat. Jewel]</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Halcyon</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sunstroke</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Stoned In Love (feat. Tom Jones)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Wake Up (feat. Keane)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Come Tomorrow</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Leaving Town (feat. Salt Tank)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead><tr><th>title</th><th>artist</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>No Ordinary Morning</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>From Where I Stand</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Come Back</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Offshore</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Don't Give Up (feat. Bryan Adams)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Spirit (Chicane Rework Mix) [feat. Jewel]</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Halcyon</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sunstroke</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Stoned In Love (feat. Tom Jones)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Wake Up (feat. Keane)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Come Tomorrow</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Leaving Town (feat. Salt Tank)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead><tr><th>title</th><th>artist</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>No Ordinary Morning</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>From Where I Stand</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Come Back</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Offshore</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Don't Give Up (feat. Bryan Adams)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Spirit (Chicane Rework Mix) [feat. Jewel]</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Halcyon</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sunstroke</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Stoned In Love (feat. Tom Jones)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Wake Up (feat. Keane)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Come Tomorrow</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Leaving Town (feat. Salt Tank)</td><td>Chicane</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**What is happening? - Google Chrome**
*Here a little explanation what i can see on Google Chrome:* The `thead` has a integer width without a decimal place (a total number). But the table with `display:flex;` and `flex-flow:column;`, the width of the table has a value with a two decimal place. If a single table has a width of `248.75px` the `thead` has a width of `248px`. The browser (in this case Google Chrome) round off the value of the width of `thead` to a total number value.

To solve this problem you have to add `1px` to the inner element (in this case `thead`) to round up the width on rendering. Now you have to hide the overflow with `overflow:hidden;` on the parent element.

Comment: I might use `calc(100% + 1px)` instead, but your hack methodology is sound.

Comment: yes you can do it too. this little hack should do the job.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to withhold the acceptance mark for a little bit to see if someone can answer the "Why" part of the question. If no such answer appears, I'll give you credit for what you've given.

Comment: added a short explanation about what's happening.